# How can I prevent images from being zoomed in/out when clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I open large images in the browser (e.g., [https://some-image.jpg](https://www.wallpapersshare.com/img/big/cat-4k-wallpaper.jpg)), Chrome will show a 'zoom-in' cursor, and zoom the image then clicked (and zoom back out when clicked again).

This happens despite there being no JavaScript on the page at all, and no event listeners anywhere in the document. The zoom happens after `onmousedown`, during or after the `onmouseup`, and before `onclick`. I have tried all the usual JS for cancelling events. For instance, this has no effect:

```
imgElement.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancel = true;
}, false);
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

**EDIT:** I should clarify that the zoom behavior I want to prevent is Chrome's default behavior for images.

Comment: It's browser's default behaviour. So, i prefer not to override this. Since some users may find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe override the cursor with anotehr cursor instead of zoom-in:

css file

```
img {
cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

That should do it

Comment: Unfortunately not. It removes the `zoom-in` cursor, but not the zoom in behavior.

Comment: Or if you want javascript use `document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.cursor = 'pointer';`

Comment: Ahh I know how!!! override the width and height because the browser is only changing the width and height of the image. `img {
height: 499px;
width: 799px;
}`

Comment: Thanks, that's a smart approach. But I need to ensure this works for all image sizes

Comment: Assign the old sizes of the image into a variable then use that variable to override the image : `var width = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width;
var height = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.height;
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.height = height
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width = width;`

Comment: Happy to help:)